# Keep podcast playing in wordpress while navigating site

Tags: wordpress, podcast

I am using wordpress and currently have a sidebar with podcasts available to play, in this case soundcloud. I have had a look on Stackoverflow but the solutions just are not working for what I need. I would like to keep the podcast playing as the user navigates through the site without it cutting out when changing page. Any help or advice on a plugin for this would be great. Soundcloud is only one of the casting platforms, there will be others like itunes and such. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well... that's not so easy, since browsing web-pages means actually reloading the page with new content. That's how the internet works ;-)

According to your question, I assume that you're not familiar with web-development and that you're using a ready wordpress theme from somewhere.

Try using a template that uses AJAX instead of full page-reloads:
http://www.wptemplate.com/themes/ajax-wordpress-themes.html
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ajax+powered+wordpress+themes&*

Comment: thanks! yes I am using a ready made theme and can open it in a new window but it's not ideal. if its a large site won't all the ajax calls make it resource heavy? I will look into those themes, it's for a news blog so will be heavily populated with content!